# How to find out if Laptop is HDMI-CEC capable?

Tags: command-line

Is there a command line utility that displays all the capabilities in the graphic card and shows information about CEC functionality in my laptop?

Comment: would be very useful .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following,

```
sudo apt-get install cec-utils libcec-dev
```

and then,

```
cec-client -l
```

It should list the devices that support it.

Please check the link/answer from superuser.com for some more information,

source:
https://superuser.com/questions/524759/determine-the-hdmi-controller-from-the-command-line